# backbone.js with backgrid.js to populate JSON

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I am using backgrid.js with backbone.js. I'm trying to populate JSON (user list) in backgrid. Below is my JSON,

```
    [{"name": "kumnar", "emailId":"kumar@xxx.com", 
    "locations":{"name":"ABC Inc.,", "province":"CA"}
    }]
```

I can access name & emailId as below,

```
    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var User = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: User,
        url: 'https://localhost:8181/server/rest/user',
    }); 

    var users = new User();
    var columns = [{
            name: "loginId",
            label: "Name",
            cell: "string"
        }, {
            name: "emailId",
            label: "E-mail Id",
            cell: "string"
        }
    ]; 

    var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
        columns: columns,
        collection: users
    });

    $("#grid-result").append(grid.render().$el);
    userEntities.fetch();
```

My question is, how do I add a column for showing locations.name?

I have specified locations.name in the name property of columns but it doesn't work.
{
        name: "locations.name",
        label: "E-mail Id",
        cell: "string"
    }

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Both backbone and backgrid currently don't offer any support for nested model attributes, although there are a number of tickets underway. To properly display the locations info, you can either turn the locations object into a string on the server and use a string cell in backgrid, or you can attempt to supply your own [cell implementation](http://backgridjs.com/#api-cell) for the locations column.

Also, you may try out [backbone-deep-model](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model) as it seems to support the path syntax you are looking for. I haven't tried it before, but if it works, you can just create 2 string columns called `location.name` and `location.province` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy to extend Cell (or any of the existing extensions like StringCell).  Here's a start for you:

```
var DeepstringCell = Backgrid.DeepstringCell = StringCell.extend({

    render: function () {
        this.$el.empty();
        var modelDepth = this.column.get("name").split(".");
        var lastValue = this.model;
        for (var i = 0;i<modelDepth.length;i++) {
            lastValue = lastValue.get(modelDepth[i]);
        }
        this.$el.text(this.formatter.fromRaw(lastValue));
        this.delegateEvents();
        return this;
    },

});
```

In this example you'd use "deepstring" instead of "string" for your "cell" attribute of your column.  Extend it further to use a different formatter (like EmailFormatter) if you want to reuse the built-in formatters along with the deep model support.  That's what I've done and it works great.  Even better is to override the Cell definitions to look for a "." in the name value and treat it as a deep model.

Mind you, this only works because I use backbone-relational which returns Model instances from "get" calls.